# How to use combined capturing groups in RegEx with string.prototype.matchAll?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I try to capture some patterns in my textInput (a string) by using the following RegEx:

```
let idPatterns = /\[id="(.*?)\"]|\[id=&quot;(.*?)&quot;]|\[id&#61;&#34;(.*?)&#34;]/gim;
```

The part that matters to me, is the "id" included as: `(.*?)`

To extract the ids, I use the following:

```
patternsArray = [...textInput.matchAll(idPatterns)];
```

My result for the following text is:

> text [id=&quot;B0076VLVXG&quot;] text

Array:

```
0: "undefined"
```

but when I reduce the idPatterns variable to

```
let idPatterns = /\[asin=&quot;(.*?)&quot;]/gim;
```

I get `"B0076VLVXG"` as result (as desired). So in conclusion, the concatenation of my idPatterns seems to be inaccurate, but works using each of them separately. How can I combine the three groups of patterns in my RegEx correctly? Thank you for your help.

```js
function getIdsCombinedRegEx(textInput) {
 
  const idPatterns = /\[id="(.*?)\"]|\[id=&quot;(.*?)&quot;]|\[id&#61;&#34;(.*?)&#34;]/gim;

  const idPatternsCollection = [...textInput.matchAll(idPatterns)];

  return idPatternsCollection;
}

function getIdsSingleRegEx(textInput) {
 
  const idPatterns = /\[id=&quot;(.*?)&quot;]/gim;

  const idPatternsCollection = [...textInput.matchAll(idPatterns)];

  return idPatternsCollection;
}

let textInput = '[id="B07Q45WX5D"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. [id=&quot;B08CQTNK8S&quot;]';

console.log(getIdsCombinedRegEx(textInput));

console.log(getIdsSingleRegEx(textInput));
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, I get `[
  [
    "[id=&quot;B0076VLVXG&quot;]",
    undefined,
    "B0076VLVXG",
    undefined
  ]
]` as expected (using Firefox 86 on Windows 10)

Comment: You do realise that a match to the first part of your combined regex will be in group 1, a match to the second part in group 2, and the third in group 3, right?

Comment: You could change your regex to `\[id(?:=|&#61;)("|&quot;|&#34;)(.*?)\1]`, then the match would always be in group 2. https://regex101.com/r/hawfs5/1

Comment: Before I combined the separate regex, I got an array like this `[0: "B0076VLVXG", 1: "B08CQTNK8S", ...]` with all relevant ids collected after using matchAll(). After combining all regex into one, the result shows `[0: undefined]`. That is where my confusion comes from. I added a code snippet, too.

Comment: Your regex is indeed smarter than mine. I'm now able to get the ids with:`idPatternsCollection.forEach( (asin, idx, arr) => {arr[idx] = arr[idx][2]});` Thank you!

Comment: It can be done even more simply than `forEach`, see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should work as is, returning the match in group 2 (as it is captured by the group in the second branch of the alternation:

```js
const idPatterns = /\[id="(.*?)\"]|\[id=&quot;(.*?)&quot;]|\[id&#61;&#34;(.*?)&#34;]/gim;

const textInput = 'text [id=&quot;B0076VLVXG&quot;] text'; 

const patternsArray = [...textInput.matchAll(idPatterns)];

console.log(patternsArray);
```

Since each alternation will return the match in a different group, it might be easier to rewrite the regex to a constant capture group. For example:

```regex
\[id(?:=|&#61;)("|&quot;|&#34;)(.*?)\1]
```

This looks for:

- the characters `[id`
- either `=` or `&#61;`
- one of `"`, `&quot;` or `&#34;` (captured in group 1)
- a minimal number of characters (captured in group 2)
- a match to what was captured in group 1 (the quote part)
- a closing `]`

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hawfs5/1/)

For your expanded data:

```js
const textInput = '[id="B07Q45WX5D"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. [id=&quot;B08CQTNK8S&quot;]';

const idPatterns = /\[id(?:=|&#61;)("|&quot;|&#34;)(.*?)\1]/gim;

const idPatternsCollection = [...textInput.matchAll(idPatterns)];

// just get group 2
const idValues = idPatternsCollection.map(m => m[2]);

console.log(idValues);
```